# Weird character generated with same HTML in different website

Tags: html, char

I have the same .html and .swf files allowed in the same hosting but using a different domain. However, you can see the character 'Â' before '©' at [infinitum.com.es/mr_frosty](http://infinitum.com.es/mr_frosty), but you don't see it, as it should be, at [bluecodestudio.com/mrfrosty](http://bluecodestudio.com/mrfrosty).

I wonder why does it show that weird character at infinitum.com.es whereas at bluecodestudio.com doesn't appear at all, using the same files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At http://infinitum.com.es/mr_frosty/, the HTTP header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` declares the encoding, and this cannot be overridden in the document itself. This needs to be fixed in the server, in global settings or in your .htaccess file. If this cannot be changed, the encoding of the files must be changed to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to fix it now.

Answer (score 2):

Â© is è, but the former is encoded in UTF-8 and being read as iso-8859-1. As you can see appearance- and meaning-wise there is absolutely no relation, but encoding-wise there is.

Basically, there's an encoding issue with the first link.

Comment: What I can't understand is how can this happen if both files are the same one!

Also, how can I fix it? Shouldn't it be read as UTF-8 as declared in the Content-Type meta?

Comment: Can be a file system thing (BOM), web server setting thing, or a file thing..